# Why won't my valid PDO connection start?

Tags: php, pdo

I have always used the mysql_* functions or the mysqli object so this is my

first run at PDO.

The file that I am currently working with is here:

```
<?
 echo __FILE__;
?>
<?

    $json='{"servername":"********","username":"**********","password":"********","database":"*********"}';
    $json=json_decode($json);


    $testConn= new mysqli($json->servername, $json->username, $json->password, $json->database);

    var_dump(mysqli_fetch_assoc($testConn->query("SELECT * FROM ssd")));


    $dsn= "mysql: host=$json->servername; dbname=$json->database";

    try{
      $conn= new PDO($dsn, $json->username, $json->password);
    }catch(PDOException $e){die('loginApi::Invalid server::failure');}
    ?>
```

the mysqli object is created without a problem as you can see

[Here: http://streamlinedesign.ml/cms.php](http://streamlinedesign.ml/cms.php)

but the PDO object keeps throwing an exception. Although I have set up the dsn exactly as the PHP manual states I cannot seem to find the issue

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: `exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /srv/disk12/2035773/www/streamlinedesign.ml/cms.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /srv/disk12/2035773/www/streamlinedesign.ml/cms.php(18): PDO->__construct('mysql: host=fdb...', '********', '*********') #1 {main}`

Comment: Remove spaces from dsn?

Comment: Ohhh wonderful! I didn't expect the answer to be that easy!

Answer (score 0):

I rebuild try/catch block for checking. Please use and let me know if there is any error message.

```
$dsn= "mysql:host=" . $json->servername . ";dbname=" . $json->database;

try{
  $conn= new PDO($dsn, $json->username, $json->password);
  foreach($conn->query('SELECT * FROM ssd') as $row) {
    print_r($row);
  }
  $conn = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Remove `foreach` if you getting solution.